# Maximize function problem

Tags: functions, maximum

I don't understand why I'm getting no solution with the Maximize function in this case:

[image]

while it returns the right result when I impose $y\leq0.999$ (or, equivalently, $x\leq0.999$):

[image]

Comment: Post code not screenshots. Copy and paste from your notebook into a block ``` ```

Comment: I get a result in Mathematica 12.3.1 see here https://imgur.com/a/bBp2wl7 however it's very complex and contains many Root objects. Using `N` to make this numerical gives `{1.58496, {x -> 0.333333, y -> 0.333333}}` which matches yours. Try with `NMaximize` instead if you just need a numerical result.

Comment: @flinty thank you! `NMazimize` worked! Sorry for screenshots, I wanted to be clearer and more concise.

Comment: When you use inexact input, such as `y <= 0.999`, `Maximize` calls `NMaximize`.  `Maximize` seems unable to solve the equations that yield the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f = -x*Log[2, x] - y*Log[2, y] -
   (1 - x - y)*Log[2, 1 - x - y];
```

To find simple forms of the exact solution, set the derivatives equal to zero. The maximum is located at

```
{arg} = Solve[{D[f, x] == 0, D[f, y] == 0,
   0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}]

(* {{x -> 1/3, y -> 1/3}} )
```

The maximum is

```
max = f /. arg

(* Log[3]/Log[2] *)

max // N

(* 1.58496 *)

Show[
 Plot3D[f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{1/3, 1/3, Log[3]/Log[2]}]}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]